How can I use React Query within a react-router loader without encountering useContext errors and while having access to isLoading and isError states?
I'm working on a React application where I use react-router for routing and react-query for data management. My goal is to fetch data within the react-router loader function, but I'm encountering issues with accessing isLoading and isError states from react-query.
API Query and Hook Definition:
import { useQuery, UseQueryResult } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { getDefaultValues } from './apiClient'
import { AxiosError } from 'axios'

export const useFetchDefaultValues = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['defaultValues'],
    queryFn: () => getDefaultValues(),
  })
}

export const getDefaultValues = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/pulse/getDefaultValues`)
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error('Error fetching default values')
  }
}


React Router Loader Function:
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async () => {
  const { data: defaultData } = await useFetchDefaultValues()
  return defaultData ? defaultData.results : []
}


import BreadCrumb from '@/components/BreadCrumb'
import DataTable from '@/components/DataGrid/DataTable'
import { fetchFulfilled } from '@/features/defaultValues/defaultValuesSlice'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useAppDispatch } from '@/Hooks/hooks'
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProgramOverviewPage = () => {
  const defaultData = useLoaderData() as Parameter[]
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultData) {
      dispatch(fetchFulfilled(defaultData))
    }
  }, [defaultData, dispatch])

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-4 h-full'>
      <div className=''>
        <BreadCrumb page='T_Program_Overview' />
      </div>
      <div className='flex-1 p-6 overflow-hidden bg-background rounded-xl'>
        <DataTable />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProgramOverviewPage


Problem:
When trying to use the useFetchDefaultValues hook inside the loader, I receive the following error:
Unexpected Application Error!
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (http://.../react-query.js:1062:29)
    ...


It seems that using react-query hooks within the loader is not working because the loader runs in a different context than React components.
Direct API Fetch in Loader (which works but lacks loading/error state handling):
import { defer, LoaderFunction } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getDefaultValues } from '@/api/apiClient'

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async () => {
  const defaultDataPromise = getDefaultValues()
  return defer({ defaultData: defaultDataPromise })
}


Problem: When fetching the API directly in the loader, I successfully get the data, but I don’t have access to isLoading, isError, or other React Query hook properties to manage the UI state effectively.
Questions:
How can I correctly use react-query within a react-router loader while avoiding useContext errors?
Is there a recommended way to handle loading and error states when performing API queries in the loader function?
If using react-query in the loader is not feasible, how can I handle loading and error states effectively when fetching data directly in the loader?
Thank you in advance for your help!

React hooks can only be called in React functions and custom React hooks, they can not be called in route loaders/actions/etc. The context issue is because there is  likely no QueryClientProvider providing a query client to the sub-ReactTree. If you are deferring loading so the route loads immediately then you'll need to handle any "loading" state/UI in the routed component. That said, the deferred data only works for the initial route loading, so any additional triggered queries would also need to have their loading conditions handled in the component.

It's just my humble opinion, but RRD route loaders and query libraries like React-Query and Redux-Toolkit Query just don't work well together. You can use a queryClient directly to trigger queries, but then it gets weird with the meta data related to them. I'd recommend foregoing the route loaders and just use React-Query like normal in the routed components.

You can't access hooks outside of React Components or custom hooks. Those are the rules of hooks by react. Hooks also aren't async, so you cannot simply await a hook.
I have a blogpost for integrating react-router with react-query, what you'd want to do is get access to the queryClient and call ensureQueryData there:
export const loader =
  (queryClient) =>
  async () => {
    return queryClient.ensureQueryData({
      queryKey: ['defaultValues'],
      queryFn: () => getDefaultValues(),
    })
  }

